# Android: How to override timeout of retrofit for particular api

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

I have the following code to set time out for all apis in my project :

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

For one of the api I want to change the time out for testing purpose, and I implemented one interceptor and added as below :

```
class CustomTimeOutInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()
        val requestID = request.header("Reuest_Id")

if(requestID?.equals(RequestID.USER_TYPE) == true) {
            val timeout = ConfigManager.getInstance(context)
            chain.withReadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .withWriteTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .withConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        }
return chain.proceed(request)
}
}
```

After this I am adding interceptor like this :

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(CustomTimeOutInterceptor(context))
    .build();
```

but it is not getting time out. I tried removing client timeouts and still it did not work. Any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

Add CustomTimeOutInterceptor Interceptor  in your OkHttpClient object like below

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(CustomTimeOutInterceptor())  // <-- this is required
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code. Already doing this. I also tried with interchanging the order by putting interceptor first as you also suggested, but did not work.